# how to call function from js file to jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I have function in 1.js can I call function from 1.js

Function in 1.js

```
function houzez_map(){//pure
    alert('test')
    }
}//pure
```

**i call to location.php**

```
function houzez_geocomplete() {
     houzez_map();
}
```

Comment: PHP code is server-side, js/jquery is client-side. Please show us more of your location.php. Probably you want to pass something from jquery to php....

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
                       
            function houzez_geocomplete() {
                                  houzez_map();
                });                         
            }
            houzez_geocomplete();
              
     
        });
    </script>

Comment: Don't add code in comments, [edit] your question and append it there

Answer (score 0):

If `houzez_geocomplete()` is a javascript function then try using like below

import the `1.js` before calling the function

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function houzez_geocomplete() {
         houzez_map();
    }
</script>
```